# Undefined Variable for mystery and fourEquals

Tags: haskell

So I've defined the two variables as such in my .hs file:

```
fourEqual
    :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
fourEqual m n p q =((m==n) && (n==p) && (p==q))
```

And

```
mystery 
    :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
mystery m n p = not((m==n) && (n==p))
```

But continuously get

```
ERROR - Undefined variable "fourEqual"
```

and the same for mystery and I do not know why. The file has been uploaded on to Hugs successfully... and all my other variables that have been defined in the same file before it, works perfectly fine, but these two.

Is there something that I am not seeing that's causing this error?

So here is my .hs file:

```
module FirstScript where
size 
    :: Integer
size = 12+13

-- The function to square an integer.

square 
    :: Int -> Int
square n = n*n

-- The function to double an integer.

double 
    :: Integer -> Integer
double n = 2*n

-- An example using double, square and size.

example
    :: Int
example = double(size - square(2+2))

-- The function of a square of double.

{-squareOfDouble 
    :: Integer -> Integer
squareOfDouble n = square (double n)-} 

-- The function of double of square.

doubleofSquare
    :: Integer -> Integer
doubleofSquare n = double (square n)

threeDifferent 
    :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
threeDifferent m n p = (m==n) && (n==p)

fourEqual
    :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
fourEqual m n p q =((m==n) && (n==p) && (p==q))

mystery 
    :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
mystery m n p = not((m==n) && (n==p))
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Could you please add the full file? Maybe there's some syntax problem with an earlier part of the code.

Comment: I've just tried your code in GHCI and it works fine. Can you provide a screen print?

Comment: Just added to my post all the code in my .hs file.

Answer (score 3):

After checking your entire file using a GHC compiler, these are the comments I have:

- Your code doesn't compile. It throws the following compile error:
  `Couldn't match expected type Int with actual type Integer`
- I ***don't*** see this error: `ERROR - Undefined variable "fourEqual"`

To solve the first compiler error, change all the `Integer` types to `Int` in their type signature or perform proper type conversions using `fromIntegral`. <s>Also it's recommended that you don't use HUGS. It has become an outdated compiler, it's last release was on 2006.</s> See AndrewC's comment below. [GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/) is a more modern compiler which I suggest you to use. Or another recommended way is to use the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/) which is actually GHC with batteries included. You can also try FPComplete's [online IDE](https://www.fpcomplete.com/) which provides an excellent way to write Haskell code if you don't want to install any software locally

Comment: Hugs is the best interpreter for beginners - quick and easy to install, and fast to run with error messages that are both clearer and less wordy than ghc's. Initial courses on Haskell rarely go beyond Haskell 98 - a standard with a design goal of not forcing courses and authors to constantly update. The only change in Haskell 2010 I would care about in an introductory course is the if-then-else layout, which is implemented in hugs anyway. There's no need to push beginners off this friendly interpreter, especially when Haskell 98 and Hugs are just not bitrotten, because they were well written.

Comment: @AndrewC Didn't know about the "clear error messages" part. I have edited the answer which tells folks to look up on your comment. Feel free to edit the answer if you wish to. :)

Answer (score 1):

I put your code into a file ab.hs and loaded into GHCI. The output of the failed compilation is below.

The error messages are basically saying you are mismatching your types i.e. Int and Integer are not interchangeable. For example, your example function has type :: Int however within that function you make a call to double which has type :: Integer. This means the return type of example will be the return type of double. They types don't match so the file wont compile. Use the same types for your functions and it will compile.

I suggest changing to GHCI as well as the error messages provide a lot of information even if they can be daunting at first.

[image]